# HTML Google chart with value argument in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, charts, google-visualization

I try to display a google chart in HTML using an argument from Javascript. my code is the following:

HTML file chart.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="chart.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
<script>
    google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);
    drawBasic(1500000);
</script>
```

JavaScriptFile chart.js:

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);

function getData(number) {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['City', '2010 Population',],
        ['New York City, NY', 8175000],
        ['Los Angeles, CA', 3792000],
        ['Chicago, IL', 2695000],
        ['Houston, TX', 2099000],
        ['Philadelphia, PA', number]
      ]);
    return data;
}

function getOptions () {
    var options = {
        title: 'Population of Largest U.S. Cities',
        chartArea: {width: '50%'},
        hAxis: {
          title: 'Total Population',
          minValue: 0
        },
        vAxis: {
          title: 'City'
        }
      };
    return options;
}

function drawBasic(number) {

      var data = getData(number);

      var options = getOptions();

      var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

The chart is loaded but the bar for Philadelphia is missing. I noticed that removing this part

```
<script>
      google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);
      drawBasic(1500000);
 </script>
```

in chart.html doesn't change the behavior. I conclude the chart is loaded right after the

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="chart.js"></script>
```

line with no argument for `number`.
How can I give my argument `number` to my chart ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to wait for google charts to load,
before drawing a chart.

which is the point of --> `setOnLoadCallback`

you pass a function to this method,
which will be called when google charts has fully loaded.

here, `drawBasic` is called with the argument,
before google charts has loaded, and it fails.

then `drawBasic` is called again from the callback,
but it doesn't have the argument, so no bar for Philadelphia

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);
drawBasic(1500000);
```

instead, use an anonymous function to pass the argument...

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function () {
  drawBasic(1500000);
});
```

---

note: unless you plan to use a *material* bar chart --> `google.charts.Bar`
you don't need the `'bar'` package...